# Fyne GUI Goroutine halts after a couple of ticks

Tags: go, goroutine, fyne

I have started to write a simple Go GUI application which - for now - only displays the current time at the top left corner. My issue is that the Goroutine which makes the clock tick stops after 2-3 seconds on my M1 Mac. The interesting thing is, that when I add a print statement next to my time update one, it runs flawlessly. Remove it, and the Goroutine just halts again after a couple of ticks. Here's the code for it:

```golang
package main

import (
    // "fmt"
    "time"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func updateTime(clock *widget.Label) {
    formatted := time.Now().Format("15:04:05")
    clock.SetText(formatted)
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Clock")
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(500, 400))

    row := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
        layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
    )

    clock := widget.NewLabel("Starting Clock")
    row.Add(clock)
    w.SetContent(row)

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(time.Second) {
            // fmt.Println("Hello")
            updateTime(clock)
        }
    }()

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here, or could this just be an issue with Fyne?

Comment: Also experimenting with Fyne and GoRoutines - but using a PC with Windows 11. Copied  your code and it works as expected for me. `fyne.App` blocks GoRoutines  once `App.Run` is called with `w.ShowAndRun`, but prior to that the GoRoutine is kicked off.